# Getting src attribute of clicked image using getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript, html

Please i need a little help with my JavaScript Code.
I'm working on this assignment. The Project is supposed to an emoji maker.

The idea is to create different emojis by combining of different images (skin, eyes and mouth)

So on image click, the clicked image is supposed to show on the preview div.
The skin first, then on top of which eyes and mouth will also be placed(I haven’t effected this with my codes). I’m still trying to get the selected skin to display large across that preview div but keep getting `undefined:1 GET file:///C:/Users/Acer/Desktop/emoji%20maker/undefined net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`

This is my Code

```js
let preview = document.getElementById('final')
let img = document.getElementsByClassName('img')
//appendImageSrc(img);
//console.log(img);
for (var i = 1; i < img.length; i++) {
  //console.log(img[i]);
  img[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    let srcs = img.src;
    console.log(preview);
    //img[i].getAttribute('src');
    preview.src = img[i];
  })

}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Emoji maker using Javascript</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="split left">
      <h2 class="head" style="color: red;"> Emoji Builder</h2>
      <div class="card c1">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title"> Select Face</h5>
          <img class="img" src="assets/skin/yellow.png" alt="yellow">
          <img class="img" src="assets/skin/red.png" alt="red">
          <img class="img" src="assets/skin/green.png" alt="green">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card c2">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title"> Select Eyes</h5>
          <img class="img" src="assets/eyes/closed.png" alt="closed">
          <img class="img" src="assets/eyes/normal.png" alt="normal">
          <img class="img" src="assets/eyes/laughing.png" alt="laughing">
          <img class="img" src="assets/eyes/rolling.png" alt="rolling">
          <img class="img" src="assets/eyes/long.png" alt="long">
          <img class="img" src="assets/eyes/winking.png" alt="wink">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card c3">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title"> Select Mouth</h5>
          <img class="img" src="assets/mouth/open.png" alt="open">
          <img class="img" src="assets/mouth/smiling.png" alt="smiling">
          <img class="img" src="assets/mouth/straight.png" alt="straight">
          <img class="img" src="assets/mouth/sad.png" alt="sad">
          <img class="img" src="assets/mouth/teeth.png" alt="teeth">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="split right">
    <h2 class="head"> preview</h2>
    <div class="centered">
      <div id="preview">
        <img id="final" src="" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>


  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-/bQdsTh/da6pkI1MST/rWKFNjaCP5gBSY4sEBT38Q/9RBh9AH40zEOg7Hlq2THRZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

This `console.log(preview);` Prints out `<img id ="final" src ="undefined" alt>` in the console. What could i be missing?

Comment: `let srcs= img.src;` - `img` is the HTMLCollection getElementsByClassName returned. Why should _that_ suddenly have a `src` property?

Comment: Use `this.src` instead of `img.src`

Comment: Change `var  i` to `let i` so the variable is properly scoped in the callback functions.

Comment: First what i see is: emoji%20maker . And maybe the problem is that you use spaces in your path. try to remove space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `img.src` try using `this.src`

```js
let preview = document.getElementById('final')
let img = document.getElementsByClassName('img')
//appendImageSrc(img);
//console.log(img);
for (var i = 1; i < img.length; i++) {
  //console.log(img[i]);
  img[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    let srcs = this.src;
    console.log(preview);
    //img[i].getAttribute('src');
    preview.src = srcs;
  })

}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Emoji maker using Javascript</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="split left">
      <h2 class="head" style="color: red;"> Emoji Builder</h2>
      <div class="card c1">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title"> Select Face</h5>
          <img class="img" src="assets/skin/yellow.png" alt="yellow">
          <img class="img" src="assets/skin/red.png" alt="red">
          <img class="img" src="assets/skin/green.png" alt="green">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card c2">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title"> Select Eyes</h5>
          <img class="img" src="assets/eyes/closed.png" alt="closed">
          <img class="img" src="assets/eyes/normal.png" alt="normal">
          <img class="img" src="assets/eyes/laughing.png" alt="laughing">
          <img class="img" src="assets/eyes/rolling.png" alt="rolling">
          <img class="img" src="assets/eyes/long.png" alt="long">
          <img class="img" src="assets/eyes/winking.png" alt="wink">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card c3">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title"> Select Mouth</h5>
          <img class="img" src="assets/mouth/open.png" alt="open">
          <img class="img" src="assets/mouth/smiling.png" alt="smiling">
          <img class="img" src="assets/mouth/straight.png" alt="straight">
          <img class="img" src="assets/mouth/sad.png" alt="sad">
          <img class="img" src="assets/mouth/teeth.png" alt="teeth">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="split right">
    <h2 class="head"> preview</h2>
    <div class="centered">
      <div id="preview">
        <img id="final" src="" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>


  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-/bQdsTh/da6pkI1MST/rWKFNjaCP5gBSY4sEBT38Q/9RBh9AH40zEOg7Hlq2THRZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using forEach loop in JS it will make your task easier . Corrected JS code below

```
    let preview = document.getElementById('final')
    let img = document.getElementsByClassName('img')
    Array.from(img).forEach((i) => {
        i.addEventListener("click", () => {
            console.log(i.src);
            preview.src = i.src;
            
        });
    })
```

> Note : I used `Array.from` method in js to convert returned nodes to an array of elements. For more info about this refer to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).

Comment: @Prisca Chidimma  welcome

Answer (score 0):

Your `img` is not a single `HTMLImageElement`. It is a `HTMLCollection`, i.e. a list of images. Variables should be named appropriately to avoid, this kind of confusion.

To refer, to the clicked image inside the click event listener, declare the `event` parameter for the listener & use `event.currentTarget` inside.

```
// naming as imgList is better than img
let imgList = document.getElementsByClassName('img')
for ( var i = 1; i < imgList.length; i++) {
   imgList[i].addEventListener("click",function(event){
       let clickedImg = event.currentTarget;
       preview.src = clickedImg.src;
   });
}
```

Comment: For some reasons this didn't work. However, no error message was displayed in the console. Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: Fixed the variable naming.